# How to create a unique index on three variables in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, coordinates, unique, unique-key

I have searched for how to create a unique index, but I haven't seen any guides doing it. I want to put a unique key on three variables in my document. x, y, and z. I'm storing coordinates, and need to make sure I can't have duplicate x, y, and z coords. Anything helps.

Edit:
I'm trying to this SQL in MongoDB:

```
CREATE TABLE mapPosition(
  x INT NOT NULL,
  y INT NOT NULL,
  z INT NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT mapPosition_x_y_z_pk PRIMARY KEY (x, y, z)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is nice way to get this functionality into your program. Its a data structure that allows for key value pairs and each key needs to be unique.

Comment: that wouldn't prevent the map from having duplicate `x`, `y` and `z` coords. Only the `key` needs to be unique (and if you try to put the coords in an object, `HashSet` and `HashMap` are not compatible with `equals()`...)

Comment: I really am just looking for the code to do it in Java.  Possibly via createIndex but I'm not sure.